# Can't get overview.html into javadoc with gradle

Tags: javadoc, gradle

Using the latest gradle, I am trying to get the standard overview.html to appear in the javadocs for my project.  I have tried several different methods of configuration with no luck.  Here's the latest:

`javadoc.ext["overview"] = "${projectDir}/src/main/java/overview.html"`

No errors are reported, however, the overview blurb does not appear in the javadocs index page.  I **can** get this to work invoking javadoc from the command line or an IDE.

Thanks for helping.  (I **have** checked the [gradle docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/external/javadoc/package-summary.html).)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure how you came up with that syntax. Starting from the [DSL reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html) for the `Javadoc` task, you should eventually arrive at:

```
javadoc {
    options.overview = "overview.html" // relative to source root
}
```

According to the docs for the Javadoc tool, this seems to be the default, but is only shown if you have at least two packages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The config that worked for me was:

    javadoc {
        options.overview = "src/main/java/overview.html"
    }

For others that went down the same rabbit hole as me, I started with:

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The config that worked for me was:
`options.overview = "src/main/java/overview.html"`

For others that went down the same rabbit hole as me, I started with:
`overview = "src/main/java/overview.html"`
but received this warning:
`Dynamic properties are deprecated: http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html`
And that document and my naivety led to the config in my question.

Comment: Apparently, the path to overview.html must be relative to the source root (as commented in the answer). An absolute path did not work for me.

Comment: What worked for me was
`javadoc {options.overview = "build/resources/main/overview.html"}`

Comment: This answer is super confusing.  The comment "relative to source root " could mean many different things.  /src or /src/main or /src/main/java or /src/resources or /src/main/java/com.example.  Anyways, declaring an explicit path src/main/java/overview.html (and putting the file there of course) was required for me to get this working

Answer (score 0):

Put the file *overview.html* inside the directory *src/main/java*.

Now update your *build.gradle* file with:

```
javadoc {
    options.overview = "src/main/java/overview.html"

}
```