# Can't get package.html into javadoc with gradle

Tags: gradle, javadoc

I have package.html files in each source directory and this worked in the past.  I'm not sure if this is due to new version of Java or new version of Gradle, but now the package info isn't being included any more.  Note: the overview.html for the project is being included.   Here is the relevant part of build.gradle:

```
task doc (type: Javadoc) {
  source = sourceSets.main.allJava
  classpath = configurations.compile
  options.overview = "src/overview.html"
}
```

This is similar to [Can't get overview.html into javadoc with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536930/cant-get-overview-html-into-javadoc-with-gradle)

I'm using Gradle version 5.6.3 and Java version 11.0.2

Comment: I observe similar behavior

Answer (score 0):

I simply replaced package.html with package-info.java and now it works.  This is not a great solution since I can't find any evidence that the package.html approach is deprecated - so it should work.   I've upgraded the versions of Java and Gradle that I use to build my project but this used to work before with Java 8 and Gradle 4.  Oh well.   That's progress I guess.